# Liquefying through long boiling

Tags: boiling

Is there a name in English for the process of turning ingredients of a dish into liquid through boiling them long enough?

Usually this happens as cook's errors, but at times it's the desired effect (e.g. you may create an excellent, smooth, creamy sauce by simmering the ingredients for a long time).

Judging by what Google Images show, it seems that "[overcooking](https://www.google.pl/search?q=overcooked&num=30&safe=off&client=firefox-a&hs=6bP&rls=org.mozilla%3apl%3aofficial&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=X-qlUuPtMMuShgeax4DQDg&ved=0CAkQ_AUoAQ&biw=1136&bih=824)" usually means burnt or nearing burnt fried/grilled food, which is definitely not the same thing.

Comment: How about "overboiling"?

Comment: Are you thinking of [reduction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduction_(cooking))?

Comment: This question might be more appropriate for [ELU](http://english.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @TylerJamesYoung Or on a cooking forum.

Comment: I thought it might be trivial, but doesn't seem so. Well, I'll try Seasoned Advice.

Comment: It's really hard to figure out what term you're looking for without a single example.

Comment: Question was re-asked here before this one was migrated in.  Suggest closing as dup and possibly merging.  http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/40108/liquefying-through-long-boiling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrase you may be looking for is "boil to (a) mush".

Answer (score 2):

It appears simply [there is no word in English](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/40108/liquefying-through-long-boiling/40109#40109) to describe this process, and you have to use descriptive expressions like "simmer until dissolved".